# Loop inside content-single

Tags: php, wordpress

I try to build an option for the user to highlight "related posts" to be shown at the bottom of a single post, so I put this code at the bottom of "content-single.php":

```
<div class="related-post">

    <?php 

        $args = array(  'post__in'      => array(38328, 38359, 21321) );//it's going to be the user choice, for example, I put three id's

        $related_query = new WP_Query($args);
        if ($related_query): 
         echo '<div class="row">';
         while ($related_query->have_posts()): $related_query->the_post();?>

             <div class="col-sm-4">
                 <?php
                 if (has_post_thumbnail()):
                     the_post_thumbnail();
                 endif;
                 ?>
                 <?php the_title() . '<br/>'; ?>
             </div>
         <?php endwhile;
         echo '</div>';
         wp_reset_postdata();       
     ?>


</div>
```

But in some posts, I get 8 diefferent posts, in some posts I don't get any posts (though I put only three id's in post__in).
I guess the problem is that I try to loop inside the main loop.
I tried with `query_posts` and with `get_posts`, doesn't work.

Any help will be appreciate!

Comment: What is ur `post_type` ?

Comment: Just after this line, `$related_query = new WP_Query($args);`, add `echo $related_query->request;`. This will print the generated SQL query. Check if your SQL query is altered is any way. if not, something is injecting posts into your custom query, if your SQL is altered, you have a bad filter. Also, take note, by default, sticky posts are included in a custom `WP_Query`, so add `'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1` to avoid sticky posts

Answer (score 0):

I think that is related to the missing `post_type` argument. Yet you need some corrections in your loop structure:

```
<div class="related-post">
<?php
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'your_post_type', 'post__in' => array(38328, 38359, 21321) );
    $related_query = new WP_Query($args);
    if( $related_query->have_posts() ){ ?> 
    <div class="row"><?php
        while( $related_query->have_posts() ){ $related_query->the_post();?>
            <div class="col-sm-4"><?php
                if( has_post_thumbnail() ) the_post_thumbnail();
                the_title();?>
            </div><?php
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();?>
    </div><?php
    }?>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

Please try to add `'posts_per_page' => 3` to the `args` array.

Comment: My post-type is post, I tried to add this argument, and it doesn't work

Comment: Please replace the provided code with your own, as it has some problems. Also try to add `'post_status' = > 'publish'`

Comment: I put your code, but I still get more posts then I should, I also get the posts: 38331, 38321, 38299, 38247, 38229. And I get 38359 twice... I do test it inside 38359 itself..No idea why this is happening

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution to this post. Hope so you are wrong with the query post.

```
<div class="related-post">
<?php
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'your_post_type', 
    'post__in' => array(38328, 38359, 21321),
    'post_status'=>'publish'
    );
$related_query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
<?php if ( $related_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <div class="row">
    <?php while ( $related_query->have_posts() ) : $related_query->the_post(); ?> 
    <div class="col-sm-4">   
    <!-- do stuff ... -->
    the_post_thumbnail();
    the_title();
    </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif;  wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</div>
```

Hope so it helps you to fetch out your Output Required.
Make sure you have post in the ID that you have mentioned in the post_in section.

Comment: Answer have been updated now and it works fine for me in the Single Page.

Comment: I still get 8 posts from that query, how is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I manage to solve this by adding this `'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1` to the arguments. thanks @Pieter Goosen